# Guardar videos en la memoria privada de la aplicación en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito guardar videos en el directorio **getFilesDir()** de la aplicación, y a la hora de guardar imagenes utilizo Bitmap, pero no funciona para videos. ¿Alguna estructura parecida para videos?
***Edit:*** Adjunto el codigo donde llama a la cámara de video.

```
            File nuevo = new File(getFilesDir(), nombre);
            String nombreArchivo = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            File archivo = new File(nuevo.getPath(), nombreArchivo);
            Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(archivo);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO);
```

En el metodo donde recibe el resultado, simplemente utilizo unos Toast.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Ejecutado correctamente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video Cancelado.", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Falló al grabar video.", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Froilan, edita tu pregunta y muestra el codigo con el que intentaste hacerlo y que error te lanzaba.

Comment: Para guardar los videos tienes que usar `OutputStream`, muestra el codigo de tu aplicación para poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: Froilán es importante lo que comenta Einer, revisa el funcionamiento básico del sitio en el [tour] y es importante modifiques tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida, revisa [ask].

Comment: Ya agregué el codigo, mi codigo no lanza errores, simplemente no genera el archivo de video.